# I Get Compiler Error : I write npm start > Error: ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/autocomplete.css

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, autocomplete

I get **npm start** compiler error and I try everything.

I try :

-npm i jquery-ui

-npm i webpack-jquery-ui

-npm i -f

I write **npm start** and

```
internal/streams/legacy.js:59
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^
Error: ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/autocomplete.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  * http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#theming
|  */
| .ui-autocomplete {
|       position: absolute;
|       top: 0;
 @ (webpack)-jquery-ui/autocomplete.js 8:0-49
 @ ./app/assets/js/vendors/index.js
 @ ./app/assets/js/layouts/header.js
 @ ./app/assets/js/layouts/index.js
 @ ./app/assets/js/main.js
 @ multi ./app/assets/js/main.js./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/menu.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  * http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#theming
|  */
| .ui-menu {
|       list-style: none;
|       padding: 0;
 @ (webpack)-jquery-ui/autocomplete.js 9:0-41
 @ ./app/assets/js/vendors/index.js
 @ ./app/assets/js/layouts/header.js
 @ ./app/assets/js/layouts/index.js
 @ ./app/assets/js/main.js
 @ multi ./app/assets/js/main.js./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/core.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| /* Layout helpers
| ----------------------------------*/
| .ui-helper-hidden {
|       display: none;
| }
 @ (webpack)-jquery-ui/autocomplete.js 7:0-41
 @ ./app/assets/js/vendors/index.js
 @ ./app/assets/js/layouts/header.js
 @ ./app/assets/js/layouts/index.js
 @ ./app/assets/js/main.js
 @ multi ./app/assets/js/main.js
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pixelplus-frontend-boilerplate@0.0.3 build: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pixelplus-frontend-boilerplate@0.0.3 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tolga\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-15T11_11_09_608Z-debug.log
```

Edit: I try;

- npm uninstall && rm -rf node_modules && npm i -f
- delete package-lock.json
- yarn install
- Node Version : v8.14.1
- Npm Version : 6.4.1
- Yarn Version : 1.22.0
- Python Version : 3.5.3

webpack.common.js =

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['env'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendors',
      minChunks(module) {
        const context = module.context;
        return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
      },
    }),
  ]
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
});
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin({
      sourceMap: false,
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
    }),
  ],
});
```

Comment: Looks like webpack doesnt understand .css modules. What loaders are you using ? Can you show your webpack config ?

Comment: @MichałLach I add  webpack.prod.js , webpack.dev.js, webpack.common.js

Comment: Ok, you need https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/ that will understand parse correctly .css files.

Comment: @MichałLach Thank you for answers but don't work. npm install --save-dev style-loader